# Jenkins polling TFS through VPN

Tags: tfs, jenkins, hudson, vpn, polling

I am attempting to integrate a few external projects to our Jenkins CI, from a remote TFS located on a separate network that requires a VPN connection.

I have already set up a new specific **Slave**, which is always connected to the VPN, and manually triggered builds work like a charm.

However, polling periodically for changes doesn't seem to work.
The **Team Foundation Server Polling Log** reports the following:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "TF.exe": CreateProcess error=3, The system cannot find the path specified
```

I assume the fact that it can't find *TF.exe* is because that is being run on the Master (which doesn't have it installed), and in our case we need to also have the polling run on the **Slave**. The Master doesn't have connectivity to TFS.

Is polling always run on the master, or can that be configured? Any other ideas on how to get this working with polling as well? Should I change the current setup and go for using a TFS Proxy instead to allow the master to poll that one locally without actual VPN access?

The TFS plugin version is 2.0, and Jenkins is 1.529

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after much research and given the lack of comments here, my only option was to downgrade to the previous stable version of the TFS Plugin.